# 8051 Serial Programming in C

Tags: embedded

I'm currently working on a project of mine and I've hit a roadblock concerning programming the 8051 microcontroller in C. I have never dealt with embedded programming before so some of the syntax is a little confusing to me. Essentially what I'm trying to do is to take the byte of data coming in from the ADC port shown and transmit that serially to a transceiver (not shown or important right now). First I should ask, is this possible? Most explanations I see just deal with the Rx and Tx ports that assume data is already coming in serially, but as you can see, I will not need the Rx port. Where should I start? I'm sorry if this is really simple, I am very new to this side of EE.

[image: Multisim]

Comment: This is basically a matter of finding two suitable examples (ADC and serial) and sticking them together, or finding one example that already does both jobs.  Note that the 8051 is a rather primitive and limited processor in modern terms; there's little reason to use one in a new design.  Really they show up in new things only because they're a cheaply licensed core that can be included in chips built for other purposes, eg, some chips that offer a radio (possibly BLE) in addition to a processor core.  Even there, they are fading from the market in favor of more modern solutions.

Comment: I hear you, Chris. I'm only using the 8051 because I need to use Multisim and it is the only programmable Microcontroller on my version. The 8051 seemed good to me to use because there is also a LOT of documentation/examples on it, so I figured it was a good place to start.

Comment: If you intend to write code in C, then 8 bitters aren't recommended since you need quite in-depth C knowledge to write proper programs for them. If you want to program in assembler then 8 bitters are fine, though 8051 is perhaps the most horrid and code-inefficient one of them all. And all major manufacturers have stopped producing it too.

Comment: Lundin, I'm not sure how correct any of those statements are. I've found plenty of tutorials online for programming an 8-bit input 8051 with serial output. It appears very common for teaching embedded programming, plus almost all chips I see nowadays will say "8051 compatible". Second, "All major manufacturers have stopped producing it" is false. Simply typing in 8051 on google will pull up thousands of different models for sale. All I was asking was if somebody had a code example, but I pieced it together myself and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in a microcontroller is manipulated by writing and reading to registers. These registers are you API, so to speak. They are what your rather arbitrary, non-physical software manipulates to get things to physically happen in real things on the processor.

That means controlling the ADC is writing to registers. This includes settings (you write to a register to enable or disable settings and set values) and one-time actions (you write to a flag to get the ADC to do something a single time and the register might reset after that). Similarly, getting data from the ADC is also reading registers. You would have to look at the datasheet of the MCU you are using to figure out what those registers are, what they do, and how they work.

If you only need to TX, you just TX and ignore the fact that the RX exists entirely.

Comment: This appears to be an external ADC with parallel output. About as stone age as 8051... there will be no registers. I assume it just spits out new parallel data at each clock cycle and that's it.